# Symfony Book, docker-compose permission denied

Tags: docker, symfony

I'm learning the Symfony framework. I started the example given in the documentation with the book. However, I have a problem with the command
`symfony new --version=5.0-6 --book guestbook`

Checking book requirements are good but the step stopping docker containers didn't work.
I got :

```sh
[WEB] Stopping Docker Containers: [ KO ]
[14654] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

And general exit code status 255

I think these are bad rights for the script and docker composes, could you enlighten me

Thank you very much

Ps : I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You likely have a permission problem, is your current user in the "docker" group ? If you do ``docker -v``, do you still have permissions issue ?

Comment: Yes, ```groups``` shows docker groupe. And docker -v already works, but i need to use sudo to list docker images for example

Comment: Could you show your ``docker-compose.yml`` file ? I'm surprised that the Symfony cmd does Docker stuff. Where did you launch this command ? Have you write permission in the folder you launched it in ?

Comment: The ```docker-compose.yaml``` is stored in the github projet cloned by ```symfony new --version=5.0-6 --book guestbook```. http://github.com/the-fast-track/book-5.0-6. The project is here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/2-project.html

Comment: I may have misunderstood the recovery method of the project. I launch this command in my home directory, i got all permissions

Answer (score 1):

Finally,
It was permission issue
On Linux command line :

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Comment: Note : Clone this book is not really necessary to complete the tutoriel of Symphony 5